# Filtering information with dropdown selection

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have problem with filtering system, which I would like to filter notices. Filtering should work by using status ID’s that every post has, for example bug-report has status ID nro. 6.

This is jQuery script I use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#status_option").change(                                                     
    function(){
        var statusValue = $('#status_option option:selected').val();
        if(statusValue == "1"){
            <?php 
                $sql_status1="SELECT * FROM notice, user, status WHERE notice.userID = user.userID AND notice.statusID = status.statusID = '1' ORDER BY noticeID DESC";
                $result_status1=mysql_query($sql_status1);
            ?>
        } 
        else if(statusValue == "2"){
            <?php
                $sql_status2="SELECT * FROM notice, user, status WHERE notice.userID = user.userID AND notice.statusID = status.statusID AND status.statusID = '2' ORDER BY noticeID DESC";
                $result_status2=mysql_query($sql_status2);
            ?>
        }                                       
        else if(statusValue == "3"){
            <?php
                $sql_status3="SELECT * FROM notice, user, status WHERE notice.userID = user.userID AND notice.statusID = status.statusID AND status.statusID =  '3' ORDER BY noticeID DESC";
                $result_status3=mysql_query($sql_status3);
            ?>
        }
        else if(statusValue == "4"){
            <?php
                $sql_status4="SELECT * FROM notice, user, status WHERE notice.userID = user.userID AND notice.statusID = status.statusID AND status.statusID = '4' ORDER BY noticeID DESC";
                $result_status4=mysql_query($sql_status4);
            ?>
        }
        else if(statusValue == "5"){
            <?php
                $sql_status5="SELECT * FROM notice, user, status WHERE notice.userID = user.userID AND notice.statusID = status.statusID AND status.statusID = '5' ORDER BY noticeID DESC";
                $result_status5=mysql_query($sql_status5);
            ?>
        }                                   
        else if(statusValue == "6"){
            <?php
                $sql_status6="SELECT * FROM notice, user, status WHERE notice.userID = user.userID AND notice.statusID = status.statusID AND status.statusID = '6' ORDER BY noticeID DESC";
                $result_status6=mysql_query($sql_status6);
            ?>
        }
        else{
            <?php 
                $sql_default="SELECT * FROM notice, user, status WHERE notice.userID = user.userID AND notice.statusID = status.statusID ORDER BY noticeID DESC";
                $result_default=mysql_query($sql_default);
            ?>
        } 
    }   
);});
```

Status is selected from dropdown:

```
<select id="status_valinta" style="width:210px" >
<option title="css/msdropdown_img/status_all.gif">All posts</option>
<option value="1" title=".../status1.gif">Notification</option>
<option value="2" title=".../status2.gif">Waiting for answer</option>
<option value="3" title=".../status3.gif">Guide</option>
<option value="4" title=".../status4.gif">Document</option>
<option value="5" title=".../status5.gif">Image</option>
<option value="6" title=".../status6.gif">Bug-report</option>
```

The problem is that when I choose the status I want from the dropdown nothing happens. Also this filtering system should work by opening the filtered information dynamically into the same page.

This is the are where the printed data shown:

```
<table width="100%" id="notices" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Sender</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
            <th>Timestamp</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ // Starting looping rows
        ?>
            <tr style="background-color:<?php echo $rows['colorCode']; ?>">
                <td>
                    <a class="opener_notice, load_data" href="notice_v2.php?id=<?php echo $rows['noticeID']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $rows['title']; ?>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $rows['firstname']; ?> <?php echo $rows['lastname']; ?>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $rows['commentID']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo date('d.m.Y, H:i:s', strtotime( $rows['sendTime'] )); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
            // Stopping the looping and closing the mysql connection
            } mysql_close();
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You obviously have no idea how hackable this is.  Part of the point of MVC, is to remove any and all DB calls from the view write.  You're site will be majorly unsecured if you continue like this, just fyi.

Answer (score 0):

you should check the source of the html page you are working on....cos as I can see and understand all the php code written here in this snippet will be executed at the server only and in jquery filteration there will only be blank spaces..

Although what you wan to achieve can be achieved by something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
<?php                   // this code will be executed on the server 
    $sql_status1="SELECT status_id, status_value FROM notice, user, status WHERE notice.userID = user.userID AND notice.statusID = status.statusID ORDER BY noticeID DESC"; // considering status_id, status_value are the required attributes
    $result_status1=mysql_query($sql_status1);
    foreach(result_status1 as $res)
         $json_obj_arr[$res[status_id]] = $res[status_value]
    echo 'var notices = '.json_encode($json_obj_arr).';';  //and we will have a json abject in our html 
?>
var notice_json = $.parseJSON(notices);       //we will parse this object 
$("#status_option").change(                                                     
    function(){
        var statusValue = $('#status_option option:selected').val();
        alert(notice_json.statusValue);   //and directly access the value corresponding to statusValue in the notice_json object
    }) //end on change
})// end document.ready
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work. I don't have all that much knowledge about json, but I tried to tweak your code without success. In your code there are values status_id and status_value, but I only have statusID, and it is used as number for values in id="status_valinta".

Comment: so what do you want to alert when the user selects some value?